# React Native Command giving error

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

Hope everyone is doing great i have a issue in react native command i made the assets folder and after that running a command

```
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res
```

but its giving me error again n again

```
Unable to resolve module `AccessibilityInfo` from `C:\AnkitaFolder\Vanilla1\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\react-native\react-native-implementation.js`: Module `AccessibilityInfo` does not exist in the Haste module map
 This might be related to https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4968
To resolve try the following:
  1. Clear watchman watches: `watchman watch-del-all`.
  2. Delete the `node_modules` folder: `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`.
  3. Reset Metro Bundler cache: `rm -rf /tmp/metro-bundler-cache-*` or `npm start -- --reset-cache`.  4. Remove haste cache: `rm -rf /tmp/haste-map-react-native-packager-*`.
```

I tried everything possible but its still not working once it worked and again its giving the same error.Version i am using are mentioned below..

```
 NPM-VER- 6.3.0 
    "react": "16.4.1",
    "react-native": "0.56.0"
"devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "23.4.2",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "5",
    "jest": "23.4.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.4.1"
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to clean npm and all caches. If its not helping maybe your bundle props is wrong or files corrupted

1. rm -rf $TMPDIR/react-native-packager-cache-* && rm -rf $TMPDIR/metro-bundler-cache-*
2. cd android && ./gradlew clean
3. Delete all node_modules
4. npm cache clean or npm cache clean --force

Or

`On windows React 0.56 not working for`[https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/19953](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/20353)`also`https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/20353

Comment: Not working at all i have tried all possible solutions

Comment: how to corect the bundle props?

Comment: sorry but i didn't get u

Comment: You running it on windows? On windows React 0.56 not working for 
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/19953

If you want to use latest. I moved from windows to Ubuntu. So here everything working :) Keep in min first of all go to package git and search for issue. If you not found there so you can open it or write it here.

Comment: yes i am using react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.56.0

Comment: but can i downgrade it and will downgrade will work i have downgraded to 0.55.4 but its still not working

Comment: Also you need downgrade babel-preset-react-native to 4 i think, babellrc i think should be: "presets": ["react-native"], react-native 0.55.4. After this clean all cache. Also you can init 0.55.4 react-native package and look to package.json